# React menu toggle typeError (gsap, object is not extensible)

Tags: reactjs, gsap, togglebutton

I having some hard time to figure out some issues on my Gatsby application (i'm new to Gatssby. Basically I'm trying to implement open, close menu functionality using GSAP. The issue I'm facing is in my *if else* conditional statement then I'm toggling between the open close menu states.

Strange thing is on my *if* statement gsap works just fine, but on *else* condition, then I add gsap function in it I get error ***"can't define property "_gsap": Object is not extensible"***. Because I'm new to React and GSAP, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong? There from this error coming from and how could I solve it?

Here is my code:

**menu.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Link } from "gatsby";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import gsap from "gsap";

import {
 Github,
 LinkedIn,
 Instagram,
 Facebook,
 Twitter,
 Close,
} from "../assets/svg/social-icons";

const Menu = ({ menuState, setMenuState }) => {
 // Create varibles of our dom nodes
 let menu = useRef(null);
 let revealMenu = useRef(null);
 let revealMenuBackground = useRef(null);

 useEffect(() => {
   if (menuState) {
     console.log("CLOSE");
     gsap.to([revealMenu, revealMenuBackground], {
       duration: 0.8,
       height: 0,
       ease: "power3.inOut",
       stagger: { amount: 0.07 },
     });

     gsap.to(menu, {
       duration: 1,
       css: { display: "none" },
     });
   } else if (!menuState) {
     console.log("OPEN");
     // ERROR COMES FROM HERE
     gsap.to([revealMenu, revealMenuBackground], {});
   }
 });

 return (
   <>
     {menuState && (
       <div ref={(el) => (menu = el)} className="hamburger-menu">
         <div
           ref={(el) => (revealMenuBackground = el)}
           className="menu-secondary-background-color"
         ></div>
         <div ref={(el) => (revealMenu = el)} className="menu-layer">
           <div className="wrapper">
             <div className="container">
               <div onClick={() => setMenuState(!menuState)} className="close">
                 <Close />
               </div>
             </div>
             <div className="menu-city-background"></div>
             <span className="menu-text">Menu</span>
             <div className="menu-links">
               <Navbar />
             </div>
             <div className="menu-social-icons">
               <IconList />
             </div>

             <button className="btn menu-resume">Resume</button>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     )}
   </>
 );
};

const IconList = () => {
 return (
   <li>
     <a className="icon social-icon" href="#">
       <Github />
     </a>
     <a className="icon social-icon" href="#">
       <Instagram />
     </a>
     <a className="icon social-icon" href="#">
       <LinkedIn />
     </a>
     <a className="icon social-icon" href="#">
       <Facebook />
     </a>
     <a className="icon social-icon" href="#">
       <Twitter />
     </a>
   </li>
 );
};

export default Menu;
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `useRef`, you can access your element (what gsap needs) with `reference.current`.

In your case, you should add `.current` to `menu`, `revealMenu` and `revealMenuBackground`, otherwise gsap won't understand what you are passing.

Example:

```
gsap.to([revealMenu.current, revealMenuBackground.current], {});
```

Also, on your return you should define your references as for example `ref={menu}` so the reference of that element gets attached to the current reference defined by `useRef`.

Last but not least, in the `useEffect` you should wrap everything within a condition to check if that ref contains a value, as such:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if(menu?.current) {
    // Do your animations here
  }
}
```

This is because of React components lifecycle, where:

1. The reference gets instanciated with null
2. `useEffect` runs and the ref will be null
3. The component renders the jsx (this is where the ref gets attached to its element)
4. Now `useEffect` will contain the references

Comment: Thank's for your response.  Error now dissapeard, but then I console.log(revealMenu.current) I get null. So it didn't return anything.

Comment: I've updated the answer to give you an idea of why that is the case; if you want to learn more about react references see this great resource: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html